# Wordpress replace character output that breaks my script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress 4.2.2 and i found a very weird problem. On a plugin i found the plugin author print an output for something like this:

```
        echo '  if (responsiveEntries!=undefined && responsiveEntries.length>0)'."\n";
        echo '      jQuery.each(responsiveEntries, function(index,obj) {'."\n";
        echo '          var curw = obj.width != undefined ? obj.width : 0,'."\n";
        echo '              cura = obj.amount != undefined ? obj.amount : 0;'."\n";
......etc
```

The problem arise on the frontend, when i debug, the output is become something like this:

```
    if (responsiveEntries!=undefined &#038;&#038; responsiveEntries.length>0)
         jQuery.each(responsiveEntries, function(index,obj) {
            var curw = obj.width != undefined ? obj.width : 0,
            cura = obj.amount != undefined ? obj.amount : 0;
```

As you can see.. the character && is replace by the safe character (& #038;).. it brokes the script... i'm wondering how to debug this issue, i already turn off unnecessary plugin and the problem is there.. so i believe its related with the themes or core wordpress

the problem only happen on post or custom post type.. when i put the shortcode on pages.. there's no problem

Any thought ?

Answer (score 0):

It seem there's default filter in wordpress called wp_texturizer() and convert_char() who convert & into `&#038;`

to solve this, i use

`remove_filter ('the_content','wp_texturize');
apply_filter('the_content',$my_content);
add_filter ('the_content','wp_texturize');`